# In Wildfly in EAR app, how one module can read a properties file in another module?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, wildfly, ear, properties-file

My question is regarding a EAR app. I would like to know how can a class in one module read a properties file which is in another module.

I am working with Eclipse Luna and Wildfly 8.2.1.

In Eclipse:
* I have a "Enterprise Application Project" named **MyEar**.
 
* I have a "Dynamic Web Project" named **MyWeb** and it is part of **MyEar**.
* I have a "Utility Project" named **MySrc** and it is part of **MyEar**.

In **MyWeb** project, I have a properties file named `app.properties` and it is located in `WEB-INF\classes` folder:

```
DefaultMaximumBatchSize=1000
```

In **MySrc** project, I have a class named `AppProperties` which reads the `app.properties` file into a `Properties` object at startup:

```
package com.srh.config;

import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Properties;

public class AppProperties {
    private static final Properties APP_PROPERTIES;

    static {
       InputStream inputStream = null;

       APP_PROPERTIES = new Properties();

       try {
          inputStream = AppProperties.class.getResourceAsStream("/app.properties");
          System.out.println("AppProperties: inputStream=" + inputStream);

          if (inputStream != null) {
             APP_PROPERTIES.load(inputStream);
          }
       } catch (Exception e) {
          System.out.println("AppProperties: Exception occured; e=" + e);
       }
    }

    public static String getValue(String propertyName) {
        if (propertyName == null || propertyName.equalsIgnoreCase(""))
            return null;
        else
            return APP_PROPERTIES.getProperty(propertyName);
    }
}
```

In **MyWeb** project, I have a listener named `AppContextListener` where I am testing the looking up of a value from the `AppProperties`:

```
package com.srh.listener;

import javax.servlet.ServletContextEvent;
import javax.servlet.ServletContextListener;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebListener;

import com.srh.config.AppProperties;

@WebListener
public class AppContextListener implements ServletContextListener {
    public AppContextListener() {
    }

    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent arg0)  { 
        String defaultMaxBatchSize = AppProperties.getValue("DefaultMaximumBatchSize");
        System.out.println("AppContextListener: contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent): defaultMaxBatchSize=" + defaultMaxBatchSize);
    }

    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent arg0)  { 
    }   
}
```

When I deployed the EAR app to Wildfly, Eclipse deployed it as **`MyEar.ear`** with these files inside it:

- `lib\MySrc.jar`
- `META-INF\application.xml`
- `MyWeb.war\META-INF\MANIFEST.MF`
- `MyWeb.war\WEB-INF\web.xml`
- `MyWeb.war\WEB-INF\classes\app.properties`
- `MyWeb.war\WEB-INF\classes\com\srh\listener\AppContextListener.class`

The `MySrc.jar` has these files inside it:

- `com\srh\config\AppProperties.class`
- `META-INF\MANIFEST.MF`

When I start the Wildfly, I get this output in `server.log`:

> AppProperties: inputStream=null 
>   AppContextListener:contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent): defaultMaxBatchSize=null

So how can the module `MySrc` read a properties file which is in the module `MyWeb`?

Thanks

Comment: If you're running in a JavaEE environment, it's usually better not to have static singletons like this.  They're troublesome.  Learn how the CDI injection framework works, and use a `@Singleton`-annotated class instead.  Then provide the properties you need for initialization through the singleton's constructor.

Answer (score 0):

I know this doesn't answer the question directly, but normally when setting up configuration properties for a Java EE web application they go in the environment entries in web.xml or in the servers JNDI tree.  Then they can be read from the servlet config.

In your example above try going with the "getInstance()" pattern with the private constructor for the singleton. Pretty sure static initializers get run on the first instanation of the class.